# Stop cron from sending mail to root for a specific process

Tags: linux, email, cron

I have a little problem with the cron daemon. I want to stop it from sending mail for a specific command. For example if I have:

```
10 * * * * someScript1.sh
15 * * * * someScript2.sh
```

I want to get the mail from someScript1 but not from someScript2. I tried setting the `MAILTO=""` but that just blocks everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redirect all output to a back hole

```
10 * * * * someScript1.sh
15 * * * * someScript2.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

See http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/06/what-does-devnull-21-mean/ for more information.

Comment: One little question... doesn't that send the output of the script to null but still sending mail?

Comment: No, that sends all output of someScript2.sh to /dev/null.

Comment: @zozo: cron sends the output, **if any**, by mail. Redirecting both `stdout` and `stderr` to `/dev/null`, means there is no output to mail.